How to search between dates
I have been trying to find a way to search between dates in Azure Data Explorer but every example or format I find on the internet has led me to more errors.
I need to be able to search our Log files between two dates. I found a previous question on here but the solutions do not seem to work for me.
Example of our date time column:

My most recent attempt was:
Logs
| where timestamp between ( datetime(2024-06-01) .. datetime(2022-06-02) )

However, the result is:

between(): all arguments are expected to have the same type 'long'


And then I also tried this example from a previous question on the same subject here:
Logs
| where timestamp >='2020- 05-25' and 'Tickets.Resolved Date' <='2020-05-26' 

Errors:


you showed a screenshot of a column named "Timestamp" (capital 'T'), but your query looks at one named "timestamp" (lowercase "t"). what is the type of "timestamp"? if it's long, you can adjust your query to filter on "Timestamp"

Your Timestamp seems to be of type long. When it should be a unix timestamp you could do it like this:
Logs
| extend Timestamp = unixtime_seconds_todatetime(Timestamp)
| where Timestamp between ( datetime(2024-07-01T00:00:00Z)..datetime(2024-07-03T00:00:00Z))

Or, if timestamp is a string which contains timestamps.
Logs
| extend timestamp = todatetime(timestamp)
| where timestamp between ( datetime(2024-07-01T00:00:00Z)..datetime(2024-07-03T00:00:00Z))

To be sure, that everything is a datetime, do this:
Logs
    | extend timestamp = todatetime(timestamp)
    | extend Timestamp = todatetime(Timestamp)

Note:
Be aware that you have timestamp and Timestamp. You have to choose the correct one.
